# Recomended CHARSET/COLLATION for bring almost every character

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I don't know if it possible or not but exists any `CHARSET/COLLATION` that holds almost every character in the world? I mean for example: `á, é, í, ó, ú, ñ` for spanish, characters for french and portuguese and so on? Any advice on this? How did yours handle multi-language sites at DB modeling level?

PS: Don't know if this is the right place to ask this if not my apologies

Comment: Is UTF-8 insufficient for your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use a `UTF-8` charset with a `utf8_general_ci` collation.